# Find all possible values which following expression can take $\sqrt{x^2-7x+6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given expression is:

$\sqrt{x^2-7x+6}$.

Now i first find values of x for which this is a valid question by putting guy inside square root equals to greater than 0. I get $x \in[-\infty,1]\cup[6,\infty] $. Now i completed the square and i got $$\sqrt{(x-\frac{7}{2})^2-\frac{25}{4}}$$.
Now from here i calculated range as x $\in$ $[0,\infty]$. Now i have taken intersection of values of  obtained and i got answer to be $[0,1]\cup[6,\infty]$. but my textbook says answer to be $[0,\infty]$. Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47597/discussion-on-question-by-j-deff-find-all-possible-values-which-following-expre).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to see what are the real numbers $c$ such that the equation
$$
\sqrt{x^2-7x+6}=c
$$
has a solution. As you observe, $c\ge0$ by definition of square root. Now we can square, getting $x^2-7x+6=c^2$ or
$$
x^2-7x+6-c^2=0
$$
which has a solution if and only if its discriminant is $\ge0$. This amounts to
$$
49-4(6-c^2)\ge0
$$
which is true for every $c$. So the range is $[0,\infty)$.

With completion of the square it's the same: the equation is
$$
\left(x-\frac{7}{2}\right)^{\!2}=c^2+\frac{25}{4}
$$
which is solvable for every $c$.

---

You are right that the function is only defined over $(-\infty,1]\cup[6,\infty)$, but this doesn't affect the range.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to take the intersection of the domain and the range, which is a nonsense.

Clearly the polynomial under the radical can reach $0$ (for $x=1$) and goes to infinity. Hence

$$[0,\infty).$$